# Command /usr/sbin/chown failed with exit code 1 (xcode6)

Tags: xcode, command

I don't know what is this.I am trying to archive my app.I know there are lots of answers for this but i can't understand any answer.so please someone know how to solve this can tell me.

```
 SetOwnerAndGroup shivamrishi:staff /Users/shriyarishi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QuoteU-cqodwskdmizaqjgavubtjxrtedhv/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/QuoteU/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/QuoteU.app
cd "/Users/shriyarishi/Desktop/QuoteU "
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/usr/sbin/chown -RH shivamrishi:staff /Users/shriyarishi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QuoteU-cqodwskdmizaqjgavubtjxrtedhv/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/QuoteU/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/QuoteU.app
```

last code

```
  chown: /Users/shriyarishi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QuoteU-cqodwskdmizaqjgavubtjxrtedhv/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/QuoteU/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/QuoteU.app: Operation not permitted
Command /usr/sbin/chown failed with exit code 1
```

image 
   https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2z_d4wEKPEFVWsxV0xUczhFck0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What are the permissions on that file? You can use `ls -lO /Users/shriyarishi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QuoteU-cqodwskdmizaqjgavubtjxrtedhv/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/QuoteU/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/QuoteU.app` to see permissions and also any flags set on the file.

Comment: nothing is happening @DanLowe

Comment: What do you mean? That `ls` command produces no output?

Comment: now it is coming check the image in code @DanLowe

Comment: Oh, right... `.app` means it is a directory in the Unix layer. So try `ls -dlO` instead, to see the actual app folder instead of the app's contents (which is what it shows in your image).

Comment: should i post a image ? @DanLowe

Comment: Sure, but if the `.app` is owned by you and has no flags (like in the image you already posted), then I'm not sure what to tell you. I was suspecting that either you do not own the `.app`, or else there was a flag such as `schg` set. (See here about flags: https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=chflags&sektion=1 )

Comment: you can check now @DanLowe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only super-user can chown files. From the `chown(8)` man page:

> For obvious security reasons, the ownership of a file may only
>   be altered by a super-user.

You should be using `sudo` if you want to change file ownership. `sudo` will require your password, and that you be in the `admin` group on the computer (i.e. you must be marked as allowed to administer the computer).

```
sudo /usr/sbin/chown -RH shivamrishi:staff \
  /Users/shriyarishi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QuoteU-cqodwskdmizaqjgavubtjxrtedhv/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/QuoteU/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/QuoteU.app
```

Comment: You just put `sudo` on the commandline before the command. There's no code involved.

Comment: @Dan I used sudo it's giving "illegal group name" error. How can I fix that?

Comment: @BharatBhushan That generally means you're trying to use `chown` or `chgrp` to set a group that does not exist on the system. Either add the group you are missing, or choose an existing group.

Answer (score 1):

This happened with me after my provisoning profile expired and I renewed it.
This error was coming for me in some pods code so I removed the pod using

```
pod deintegrate
```

please check [this](https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-deintegrate), superb way to remove pods entirely from your project.

Then `pod install`.

It worked for me!

Comment: you saved my life. only this way works for me.